# toggleClass() doesn't work after first time

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

See my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/XmEvdm

Click on the red box. It rotates and now the blue box appears.
Click the blue box. It doesn't switch back to the red box.

I'm pretty sure the JQuery code for the toggleClass part is correct, so why isn't it working?

Tks!

```js
var vCard = $("#card");

vCard.on("click", function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

```css
@mixin prefix($prop, $val)
{
  -webkit-#{$prop}: #{$val};
  -moz-#{$prop}: #{$val};
  -ms-#{$prop}: #{$val};
  #{$prop}: #{$val};
}

.container
{
  width:200px;
  height:260px;
  position:relative;
  perspective:800px;
}

#card
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  @include prefix(transform-style,preserve-3d);
  @include prefix(transition, transform 1s);
  @include prefix(backface-visibility, hidden);
  @include prefix(transform-style, preserve-3d);
}

 #card.flipped
{
  @include prefix(transform, rotateY(180deg));
}

#card figure
{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  @include prefix(backface-visibility, hidden);
}

.front
{
  background-color:lighten(red,30%);
}
.back
{
  background-color:lighten(blue,30%);
  @include prefix(transform, rotateY(180deg));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: It's to do with your styling, when you click on card, it moves outside of the card container and so you can no longer click on that element

Comment: Your listener on vCard doesn't works after first time. You can check this by adding alert('test') to it.

Comment: @user1636505 It is working, it just isn't being fired

Comment: @jumpingcode I'm agree with you, it's just my poor English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWybrd

Remove `@include prefix(backface-visibility, hidden);` from `#card`

Answer (score 1):

the event fired when its bind to `section`.

```
$('section').on("click", function()
{
 console.log('clicked'); $(this).children('div').toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

so as @jumpingcode commented, its related to your css making the div changing position.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked for me.

I removed from .card.flipped the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and also   `backface-visibility:hidden;` and I replaced those with `-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;`.